# restart splunk services via powershell

Tags: powershell

I cannot find any PS script to restart splunk services.
I just wonder whether it can be doable to restart splunk service.

Usually it is run in command and change to splunk folder first
C:\program files\splunkuniversalforwarder\bin --then run command as below:
splunk restart

Comment: Powershell supports all CMD commands/features so you can just run that command in a PS script to perform your restart.  if you know the service names you would also be able to use the `Restart-Service` cmdlet

Answer (score 1):

I would try one of the following:

`Invoke-Expression "C:\program files\splunkuniversalforwarder\bin\splunk.exe restart"`

**OR**

`& "C:\program files\splunkuniversalforwarder\bin\splunk.exe restart"`

Comment: Make sure to include quotes around program files though: `Invoke-Expression "C:\\'program files'\splunkuniversalforwarder\bin\splunk.exe restart"`

Comment: @YannStoneman the entire string is in quotes so the space is already covered. What you have wouldn't work regardless though since you'd need to wrap the whole path, the way you have it is adding quotes into the path (and not sure why the double backslash before program files is needed either). You could just pull the close quote up so the quotes only envelope the splunk.exe path and not include the `restart` argument inside the quotes